# Aligning data from NetCDF with shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, shapefile

I am currently working on a project in QGIS where I'm extracting temperature data from a NetCDF file to subnational regions. I've encountered an issue that I hope someone here can help me understand.

Problem Description:
I am using a shapefile that represents subnational regions, but it only partially overlaps with the temperature data from the NetCDF file. For example, countries like the USA are not fully covered by the shapefile. However, when I view the temperature data, it seems that these countries should still fall within the areas covered by the temperature data. Despite this, when I use the zonal statistics tool, I receive missing data for these countries.

Could this issue be due to a difference in coordinate systems between the NetCDF file and the shapefile? Or is there another reason why the temperature data isn't aligning correctly with the subnational regions in my shapefile?

Additional Information:
QGIS version: 3.23; [image]A screenshot of the issue is attached.

Comment: Not coordinate reference so much as origin. Pretty sure there's an answered Q&A here on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the extent (longitude positions) from (0 to 360) to (-180 to 180). To do this in QGIS, you need to reproject your image data using the [Warp (Reproject)](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterprojections.html#warp-reproject) tool. Use the parameters numbered in red color:

[image]

While the Source and Target CRS are optional and should be the same, I always prefer to assign them.

The most important step is step 4, where you need to assign the output raster extent:

```
-te -180 -90 180 90
```

You can refer to [gdalwarp](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html#cmdoption-gdalwarp-te) for more information.